2000s movie about domestic abuse/child abuse

This movie is in English.
It was more than likely a Lifetime movie.
I can't remember how long it was.
This movie's release year is somewhere around 2000-2013, though it
could be older, as I watched it when I was really young.

It starts off with a little boy running away from his dad. The little boy hides in the closet and calls the police, he gets the police on the phone and he tells them what's going on.
His dad or step dad finds him and grabs him.
The police show up later and find the little boy tied to the bed with beat marks on him.
I think the police take him to foster care or somewhere else.
That's where he meets this girl, whom he becomes friends with – I think she may or may not have had a burn mark on her face. You later find out that the reason she is there is because her daddy or step daddy put her in a bathtub with boiling hot water.  
At the end of the movie, it shows like this screen that said if you are being abused, or if you know someone who is being abused, call a number. I believe – I'm not sure now. 

The movie is called, For the Love of a Child (2006). 

In the 1950s, two actresses set up a charity home for "orphans" (children who were purposely abandoned and shunned because of their mixed ethnicity). The children find themselves being loved and looked after properly. 

Movie part 1:



The movie is divided into about 5 parts. They're all on YouTube.

Indeed, but please describe why or at least paste a short synopsis. Other readers might not know the film.

Here is a link to more information:m.imdb.com/title/tt0479917/synopsis?ref_=m_tt_stry_pl

Here is the link to part 1 of the movie in Youtube:https://youtu.be/ROqD_NweYME

@DeedeeJohnson Your IMDB link isn't working. In any case, you should edit the important information from that link into your answer.

@DeedeeJohnson thank you so much !!! I have been searching everywhere could not find it

I'm glad I could help!

@SammyTee You can click on the tick mark which means the answer is correct.
